# get all<p> text in <div> using agility html package

Tags: html, html-agility-pack

i tried to get all `<p>` tags inside the  `<div>` using agility html package.  but i only could get first

tag from the div.

```
<div  id='bodayDiv'>
<p> hi </p>
<p> what is app </p>
<p> in the room </p>
</div>
```

i used this code

```
//div[@id='bodyDiv']/p/text()
```

or this

```
  //div[@id='bodyDiv']//p
```

but i only could get first `<p>`

Answer (score 0):

if you want get the text of all paragraph nodes you can try this:

```
//div[@id='bodyDiv']/p/child::text()
```

I suggest you to read this http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#location-paths

Answer (score 0):

the solve of this problem is by using SelectNodes

```
     string PageFull = "";
 foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node2 in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='bodyDiv']/p/text()"))
  PageFull = PageFull + "<p>" + node2.InnerHtml + "</p>"; ;
```